# Docker run vs create

Tags: docker

*What is the difference between `docker run` and `docker create` commands?*

I usually use `run` but sometimes in documentation I see `create`.

Docker's `--help` tells

```
create    Create a new container
run       Run a command in a new container
```

Does it mean that `run` is used when we need to pass a command to a new container? What's the aim of `create` then?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/)

> The docker create command creates a writeable container layer over the
>   specified image and prepares it for running the specified command. The
>   container ID is then printed to STDOUT. This is **similar to docker run**
>   -d **except the container is never started**. You can then use the docker start  command to start the container at any point.
>
> This is **useful when** you want to **set up a container** configuration **ahead**
>   **of time** so that it is ready to start when you need it. The initial
>   status of the new container is created.

Comment: Emphasizing the similarity, --run accepts ALL the same arguments as --create (with the addition of just --detach, --detach-keys, and --sig-proxy), see https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

Answer (score 184):

`docker run` = `docker create` + `docker start`.

Comment: Actually, and I just spent a couple hours learning this, `docker run` = `docker create` + `docker start` + `docker attach`. Without `attach`, the started container runs in the background

Comment: Yep, and you can also use `docker start -a` to attach, or `docker start -ai`

Answer (score 19):

`docker create` command [creates a writeable container from the image and prepares it for running](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/).

`docker run` command [creates the container (same as `docker create`) **and** starts it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Comment: U wrote "docker run creates the container (same as docker create) and runs it." <--- circular definition ,and you haven't established the difference between exec and start,and what you refer to as "runs it".   (And when u say "runs it" if we look at your definition of run in docker run, it means create and run,so you'd end up with an infinite number.. so presumably you mean something less than that when you say "runs it".. but then you should distinguish "runs it" from exec and start, do you mean start and exec or just start). Perhaps -d means start no exec.  and without -d is start and exec

Answer (score 11):

The other answers have this covered but I thought I'd show the equivalent shell command-lines because it makes it really clear:

```
$ docker run myimage
```

is the same as

```
$ docker start -a $(docker create myimage)
```

Here, `docker create` is used to create a container from the named image and outputs the created *container id* and `docker start` is used to start the container with that id. The `-a` option causes the terminal to attach so that the container runs in the foreground which is the default behaviour of `docker run`.

A container that has been created but never started will have a `Created` status; this can be seen with `docker container ls -a`.

Answer (score 9):

I'm new to docker and just got around to playing with it;

My take is that **docker run** essentially does the following: (in the order of..) **docker create**, **docker start**, **docker attach** , since it immediately attaches to the active shell after you do the **'run'** command.

Comment: Just posted a comment above about this before I noticed your answer. I wish I had seen this an hour or so ago.

Answer (score 7):

**to create a container:**

[image]

**to start a container:**

[image]

**to create and start with a single command:**

[image]

**Now to understand we must dig deep with create and start.**

Process of creating a container is taking the file system from image, and kind of prep it for use in the new container. When we create the container we are just prepping or setting up the file system snapshot to be used to create the container to actually start the container.
[image]

So creating container is about the file system starting it is about actually executing the startup the command.
And to start the container, we actually execute the start up command that might start up the process.

Lets see it in terminal:
When I run command "sudo docker create hello-world" it prints bellow output.
[image]

In the output we saw characters printed out. This is the ID of the container that was just created, Now I can actually execute the hello world command inside of this container by running Docker start.
[image]

So what happened here, first off we kind of prop the container by getting the file system ready.
Then after that we actually executed the primary start up command in there with Docker start.

**-a** in the docker start command is for watching output from the container and print it out to your terminal.

So there is very small difference between Docker run and docker start, by default Docker run  is going to show you all the logs or all the information coming out of the container. By default Docker start is the opposite Docker start is not going to show you information coming out of the terminal.

Now you know when you need to use Run / Create / Start

Answer (score -5):

**Docker run** is basically for running commands in the container.

```
docker run -it <Container Name> /bin/bash
```

The above is for creating a bash terminal. And make us use bash commands in the container.

**Docker create** is to create a container from an Docker Image.

```
docker create -d /var/lib:/var/lib --name docker-ubuntu ubuntu
```

The above is to create a docker a container of the name "docker-ubuntu" from the image "ubuntu"

Comment: You can do `docker run -it <Container name>` without then doing /bin/bash. For example the ruby one will autorun an executable called irb. Also, you can do run -d , that's done with dockersamples/static-site  that doesn't log on. So I think it doesn't do exec but it just starts it.

Comment: with ‘docker run’ you can run if container is already created and create then run if not